# EF 5 Code First Windows Form application: how to handle data validation?

Tags: winforms, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, validation

I'm trying to figure out what's the best approach to validate user input data in a Windows Form (Code First) application.

I know how to add Data Annotation and how to use them in an MVC application, but I don't know how to use them in Windows Forms.

So far the only (ugly) way I've found is handling Textbox leave and similar events, but there must be a better way.

I just can't find anything on the web: each time I find references to some web scenario, as Code First is only used in web applications (that probably is the truth).